# Intellij says that this can be a Null-Pointer. But according javadoc

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
  private boolean checkStatusAct(Contract contract) {
        if (contract.getActs() == null || contract.getActs().isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        } else if (contract.getActs() != null || (!contract.getActs().isEmpty())) { //here
            for (ContractAct contractAct : contract.getActs()) {
                if (contractAct.getStatusId() == 15) { 
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Isn't it successively checked one by one and if it's not null (!= null || .isEmpty()) it never produces a NullPoi

Comment: the entire else if doesn't make sense. You already know that that is always going to return true. The lines after that might give problems, since you haven't checked whether or not it is empty. if you wanted that, you would need a logical AND, not a logical OR

Comment: it's either the `contract` object and `contractAct` under the loop that can be null

Comment: I think you need to learn [De Morgans laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) `not (A or B)` = `(not A) and (not B)`.  And `not (A and B)` = `(not A) or (not B)`.

Comment: In theory, the `getActs()` calls could return different values ... or the collections that they return could change (e.g. during the iteration!).  However, if either of those are true you have a problem that cannot be solved "locally" in this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jav 8 or higher version. Assuming `contract.getActs()` is a list. You don't need to write else: You can do like

```
private boolean checkStatusAct(Contract contract) {
    if (contract.getActs() == null || contract.getActs().isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    return contract.getActs().stream().anyMatch(c -> c.getStatusId() == 15);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
contract.getActs() != null || (!contract.getActs().isEmpty())
```

will throw a NullPointerException if `contract.getActs()` returns null. In that case `contract.getActs() != null` is false and because of the `||` operator the JVM must evaluate `contract.getActs().isEmpty()` which will throw the NullPointerException.

To correct this you should write

```
contract.getActs() != null && (!contract.getActs().isEmpty())
```

But this is effectively not needed, because your first `if` condition already handles the cases where `contract.getActs()` or `contract.getActs().isEmpty()`. It would be better to rewrite your code as

```
    private boolean checkStatusAct(Contract contract) {
        if (contract.getActs() == null || contract.getActs().isEmpty()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            for (ContractAct contractAct : contract.getActs()) {
                if (contractAct.getStatusId() == 15) { 
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Starting from Java 8 you can also use streams (navnath's solution).

Comment: Using java 8 or higher version, we can replace for loop with `contract.getActs()
 .stream()
 .anyMatch(status -> status == 15);`